# UITableviewHeader hides top cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, nstableviewheader

I'm setting the `tableHeaderView` of a `UITableView`, but it is hiding the top cells of the table. In my case, I want to show tableview header I have used all possible solutions but not works. Please help.

```
UIView *headerView = self.headerView;

[headerView setNeedsLayout];
[headerView layoutIfNeeded];
CGFloat height = [headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

headerView.frame = ({
    CGRect headerFrame = headerView.frame;
    headerFrame.size.height = height;
    headerFrame;
});



NSLog(@"Header Frame : %@",headerView);
self.reviewsTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

[image: View debugger screenshot]

Comment: log value of height and check if it is not zero

Comment: @DeepakKumar No, its not zero.

Comment: In my case first three cells are not visible into tableview.

Comment: Do any have idea to fix this?

Comment: Once try to add the tableview header height UITableViewDelegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was work around this issue, In my case real issue was with constraints in the storyboard.

> You have to reset constraint from the storyboard.

Or if you are setting it programmatically then you needed to call `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` method after setting of constraints to the widget.

Answer (score 1):

try writing the below lines at the end
 `[self.tableView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  [self.tableView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];`

if you set headerview using storyboard then it will become easy

Comment: Friend your idea little match with my case, Actually i updated my header xib constraints & worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in viewDidLoad. Instead do it in viewWillLayoutSubviews. This works for me.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [_headerWrapper setNeedsLayout];
    [_headerWrapper layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat height = [_headerWrapper systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    CGRect headerFrame = _headerWrapper.frame;
    headerFrame.size.height = height;
    _headerWrapper.frame = headerFrame;
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = _headerWrapper;
}
```

Comment: Then check that the height that your setting is correct or not. Also, check your constraints in the headerview because then only will UILayoutFittingCompressedSize return the correct dynamic height.

Comment: It seems my constraint was incorrect. Its worked for me   UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.headerView.frame];
 [headerView addSubview:self.headerView];
 self.reviewsTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;